# How to set a <div id=> using a string in c#?

Tags: c#, html, razor

In the code below, how can the "divId" string be passed into the div id= on the view ?

Note: @divId, '@divId' did not work.

```
@{
    for (int i = 1; i <= noOfColumns; i++)
    {
        string _fileName = string.Format("TextFileNumber_{0}.txt", i.ToString());
        string divId = "div" + i.ToString();

        <div id="???">@Html.Action("GetHtmlEditorFile", "HtmlEditorModal", new { fileName = _fileName })</div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a ActionLink, depending on the functionality to be implemented, but the sintaxis its:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Text", "Action", 
      new { @class = "my-class", id = "div_id"})
```

Grettings

Answer (score 0):

you should use @(divId). you are missing parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

It is div="@divId". It didn't work before because the string variable was out of scope on my original code.